# Network manager is not detecting wifi networks

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet, atheros

I used to get connected to the internet without any issues earlier using my router(DLINK DSL-2730U) . I tried to configure new router(TP-LINK TL-WR841N) by running following command:

```
sudo ppoeconf wlan0
```

After that my network manager is not able to detect any Wifi networks.
[Network Connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWxAT.png)
However the networks are available when I scan using  "Wifi Radar". But I am not able to connect through that either.

If i run : `$ iwlist wlan0 scan`

it gives - `wlan0    No scan results`

If i run : `$ sudo iwlist wlan0 scan` gives - list of all available wifi connections

I ran this test ([My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205)) and here is my result
http://paste.ubuntu.com/14309114/

Can somebody please help me.

Answer (score 10):

Yesterday, I upgraded from Ubuntu 16.10 to Ubuntu 17.04 and my wifi stopped working.

I noticed that I could still set up wifi manually on the console but the network manager applet wouldn't show any wifi spots and also not the active connection.

After spending 3 hours on the problem, I could fix it by a very simple step, namely modifying `/etc/network/interfaces` by removing (or commenting out using #) the following two lines:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
```

I hope this might be useful for others!

Comment: Thank you so much! You just saved me a lot of trouble...already spent 2h on that :)

Answer (score 6):

SOLVED

Go to

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

and deleted this line (Apparently, the above line is used to disable wifi network!)

```
iface wlan0 inet manual
```

and then restart network manager using

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: Thanks, man saving my time

Answer (score 1):

Run this command and hopefully it will reset your connection.
`sudo service network-manager force-reload`

Comment: No this does not help. I think the issue is ifconfig is returning wlan0 and wlan0: avahi (refer http://paste.ubuntu.com/14309114/). I think issue will be resolved if I can remove "wlan0:avahi"

Answer (score 0):

looks like the distro may have difficulty connecting to mixed router 2.4 G signals. Set your router to non 1.n (1.b) to connect to wifi