# Wifi networks are not showing in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, wireless

Very recently I have made up my mind to use Ubuntu. Firstly installed the 14.10 version and that didn't go well. On that particular version the wireless network option was not visible. I couldn't turn on the wireless connections. After that I re-installed the 16.04 version, in which the option is showing that wireless network is there but no network is showing up. Any suggestion how to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm using a Fujitsu Lifebook.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wifi doesn't work after suspend after 16.04 upgrade](http://askubuntu.com/questions/761180/wifi-doesnt-work-after-suspend-after-16-04-upgrade)  It may work if Network Manager is messed up because of a bug and sometimes sees wifi devices as ethernet

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wifi network list not showing in ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775165/wifi-network-list-not-showing-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: Possible solution: https://askubuntu.com/a/921392/427233

Comment: I had the same problem: many wifi listed but not mine. Than I found out, my wifi adaptor does not support channel over 12. So, from modem I changed channel to 10 instead 13. Its working now. So, need to check your modem information at this link: my model was (BCM4313) https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardwareSupportComponentsWirelessNetworkCardsBroadcom

Comment: For those who are still looking for some solution, I searched for several days, the solution is therefore to update the kernel to 5.10 or 5.12 example, I had 5.8 on 20.04.2 LTS with a dual boot, neither wireless or bluetooth worked, I upgraded the kernel to 5.12 via https://askubuntu.com/a/1291835/855698 and it works now.

I hope it will help those who will have this trouble.

Answer (score 72):

[This](https://askubuntu.com/a/775181/474809) helped solve the problem for me.

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager
```

or

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

I am still looking for a permanent solution, but this solves the issue till restart.

---

**Update**

Suffered from similar symptoms again. I had a stable 16.04 running smoothly for months and then suddenly yesterday the WiFi just stopped working. No networks would show on the nm applet. Tried quite a few suggestions (including my own) and none worked.

Finally realized that my last upgrade didn't go too well and had crashed in between. Removed the `dkpg` locks and ran `sudo apt-get upgrade`. A reboot later, all was back to normal.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Ubuntu network manager seems quite fragile!

Comment: Any updates on the research for the permanent solution?

Comment: this worked for me too. Do you know any permanent solution?

Comment: But I can't run an `apt upgrade` without Internet...

Comment: Add a line `greeter-setup-script=service network-manager restart` into the file `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf` to restart network-manager every time before you enter the greeter.

Answer (score 11):

- Go to Terminal and type `lspci`
- Find the name of your wireless adapter
  eg: `Network controller:  Intel Corporation wireless ....`
- Go to **System settings > Software and Updates > Additional Drivers**
- If you see name of your Wireless Adapter. Check the adapter is enabled on not. If it is not enabled, click on **Using XXYY** your adapter name
- Click on <kbd>Apply Changes</kbd>
- This will install device drivers from manufacturer if available. Once installation is complete you will be asked to restart.

Comment: this helped me lot saving time.

Comment: this worked for me

Comment: What if you don't see the name of your Wireless Adapter on the list of Additional Drivers?

Comment: Thanks for this. In my case the Wi-Fi adapter just stopped working several days ago. I'm not sure if the user was prompted for an update, but I kind of doubt that since he doesn't even know the password. For whichever reason, the Wi-Fi device was not being used so I turned it on, like you suggested, and then had to setup a password for secure UEFI. After a reboot I was prompted by the MokManager to input the password. Boot up back into ubuntu aaaand Wi-Fi is back.

Answer (score 2):

Install rfkill

```
sudo apt-get install rfkill
```

then run this command

```
rfkill unblock all
```

check if the wifi is working. If not do this

```
sudo nano /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state
```

then you will see some settings. Set everything to "true" reboot your system

give this command in terminal

```
rfkill list
```

you'll see that some are softblocked and hardblocked. All of them should be 
"no".

If it's not "no" then you need to somehow turn them to "no". I did this and it worked for me

```
sudo modprobe -r acer-wmi
cd /etc/modprobe.d
sudo nano blacklist.conf
```

Then add blacklist acer-wmi as a new line at the end of the file.

then save the file by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> ,close it and reboot the system. It should work

Answer (score -1):

Go to system setting->Network . where you find all the wireless or wifi avaiable there.

Comment: system>software and settings>additional drivers  check if any wireless drivers are listed for your laptop.

Comment: i have same problem on my lenovo . use this command :-sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service    fix my issue.

Comment: When I go to All Settings->Network->Wireless it says airplane mode is on and wireless is off all my networks report being out of range. I can turn airplane mode off but it does not let me turn wireless on.