# wifi network list not showing in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless

Initially I connected to a wifi network, but after an hour I could not find other wifi networks available. Still, I am able to use internet.

Comment: This post permanently solved the issue for me:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/769521/wifi-networks-are-not-showing-in-ubuntu-16-04 Check the **Update** section in the [answer by Sandeep Deb](/a/780493/454520).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've been having the same issue. Restarting network-manager usually fixes it (`sudo systemctl restart network-manager` or `sudo service network-manager restart`
), but it crops up again after rebooting.

Comment: let me try. But how to solve this issue permanently?

Comment: Once the fix gets verified you will get it through regular updates