# RT3290 WiFi not listing connections in ubuntu gnome 16.04

Tags: networking, wireless, bluetooth, ralink

I am using HP laptop (15-r022TX) with RT3290 network card. There was no bluetooth already. On one fine morning Wifi also stopped working.

I installed and reinstalled with older and newer versions of Ubuntu. Each time I tried

1. [wifi network list not showing in ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775165/wifi-network-list-not-showing-in-ubuntu-16-04/775181#775181)
2. http://onthim.blogspot.in/2015/06/install-ralink-rt3290-wi-fi-driver-on.html
3. [How to install wifi driver Ralink RT3290](https://askubuntu.com/questions/545238/how-to-install-wifi-driver-ralink-rt3290)
4. [How do I get a Ralink RT3290 wireless card working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253632/how-do-i-get-a-ralink-rt3290-wireless-card-working)

But nothing worked except that now I can enable and disable WIFI and bluetooth. The network names (SSID) are not listed.
[image: Wifi]
I am now using Ubuntu Gnome 16.04. Now I am stuck at this. Please help... 
[image: No SSID list]

This is the output of 'wireless-info.txt':

```
    ########## wireless info START ##########

    Report from: 14 Jun 2017 18:40 IST +0530

    Booted last: 14 Jun 2017 00:00 IST +0530

    Script from: 25 Mar 2017 07:04 UTC +0000

    ##### release ###########################

    Distributor ID: Ubuntu
    Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
    Release:    16.04
    Codename:   xenial

    ##### kernel ############################

    Linux 4.8.0-54-generic #57~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 24 16:22:28 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

    Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

    ##### desktop ###########################

    GNOME

    ##### lspci #############################

    08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [103c:2212]
        Kernel driver in use: r8169

    0a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
        DeviceName:  
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter [103c:18ec]

    ##### lsusb #############################

    Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b40e Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HP Truevision HD camera
    Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c064 Logitech, Inc. M110 corded optical mouse (M-B0001)
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

    ##### PCMCIA card info ##################

    ##### rfkill ############################

    0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
    1: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: yes
        Hard blocked: no

    ##### lsmod #############################

    cfg80211              581632  0
    hp_wmi                 16384  0
    rt3290sta            1159168  1
    sparse_keymap          16384  2 intel_hid,hp_wmi
    mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
    wmi                    16384  3 mxm_wmi,nouveau,hp_wmi

    ##### interfaces ########################

    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

    ##### ifconfig ##########################

    eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eno1' [IF1]>  
              UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
              RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
              Interrupt:16 

    enp8s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp8s0' [IF2]>  
              inet addr:172.16.5.72  Bcast:172.16.7.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
              inet6 addr: fe80::4d08:b07e:64d3:ee09/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:61076 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:35827 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
              RX bytes:78091534 (78.0 MB)  TX bytes:3094398 (3.0 MB)

    lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
              inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
              inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
              UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
              RX packets:7149 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:7149 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
              RX bytes:883954 (883.9 KB)  TX bytes:883954 (883.9 KB)

    ##### iwconfig ##########################

    lo        no wireless extensions.

    enp8s0    no wireless extensions.

    eno1      Ralink STA  ESSID:""  Nickname:"RT3290STA"
              Mode:Auto  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
              Bit Rate:1 Mb/s   
              RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
              Link Quality=10/100  Signal level:0 dBm  Noise level:0 dBm
              Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
              Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

    ##### route #############################

    Kernel IP routing table
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
    0.0.0.0         172.16.4.1      0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp8s0
    169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp8s0
    172.16.4.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     100    0        0 enp8s0

    ##### resolv.conf #######################

    nameserver 127.0.1.1
    search cusat.ac.in

    ##### network managers ##################

    Installed:

        NetworkManager

    Running:

    root      1074     1  0 18:32 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

    ##### NetworkManager info ###############

    GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp8s0
    GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
    GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
    GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
    GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
    GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
    GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
    GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12
    GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp8s0' [IF2]>
    GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
    GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
    GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
    GENERAL.UDI:                            /virtual/device/placeholder/1
    GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp8s0
    GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
    GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
    GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
    GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
    GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
    GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
    GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     enp8s0
    GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       060b69b3-86dc-4659-910b-18fd7a1ca6ef
    GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
    GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
    CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
    CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
    CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
    WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
    CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{1,2}
    CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   a1ff7981-cdbd-39ea-98ed-92e0c1c7027f | Wired connection 1
    CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[2]:   060b69b3-86dc-4659-910b-18fd7a1ca6ef | enp8s0
    IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         172.16.5.72/22
    IP4.GATEWAY:                            172.16.4.1
    IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
    IP4.DNS[1]:                             10.0.0.2
    IP4.DNS[2]:                             10.0.0.3
    IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          cusat.ac.in
    DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_routers = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_wpad = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = 172.16.4.2
    DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       expiry = 1497531771
    DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       routers = 172.16.4.1
    DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
    DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       ip_address = 172.16.5.72
    DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       domain_name = cusat.ac.in
    DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       broadcast_address = 172.16.7.255
    DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 86400
    DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       domain_name_servers = 10.0.0.2 10.0.0.3
    DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.252.0
    DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       network_number = 172.16.4.0
    DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       requested_host_name = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 172.16.4.2
    IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::4d08:b07e:64d3:ee09/64
    IP6.GATEWAY:                            

    GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eno1
    GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
    GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
    GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Ralink corp.
    GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe (Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter)
    GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rt2860
    GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 
    GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
    GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'eno1' [IF1]>
    GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
    GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
    GENERAL.REASON:                         42 (The supplicant is now available)
    GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:0a:00.0/net/eno1
    GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
    GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
    GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
    GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
    GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
    GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
    GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
    GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
    GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
    GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
    GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
    CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
    CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
    CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
    WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
    WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
    WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
    WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
    WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
    WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     no
    WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
    WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
    WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   no
    CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{0}
    CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   10953013-4c3d-4251-be15-910924e67ca3 | Hotspot

    SSID  BSSID  MODE  CHAN  FREQ  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  ACTIVE  * 

    ##### NetworkManager.state ##############

    [main]
    NetworkingEnabled=true
    WirelessEnabled=true
    WWANEnabled=true

    ##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

    [main]
    plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
    dns=dnsmasq

    [ifupdown]
    managed=false

    ##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

    [[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot]] (600 root)
    [connection] id=Hotspot | type=wifi | autoconnect=false | permissions=
    [wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'eno1' [IF1]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Dope
    [ipv4] method=shared
    [ipv6] method=auto

    ##### iw reg get ########################

    Region: Asia/Kolkata (based on set time zone)

    country 00: DFS-UNSET
        (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
        (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
        (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
        (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
        (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
        (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
        (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
        (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

    ##### iwlist channels ###################

    lo        no frequency information.

    enp8s0    no frequency information.

    eno1      11 channels in total; available frequencies :
              Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
              Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
              Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
              Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
              Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
              Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
              Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
              Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
              Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
              Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
              Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
              Current Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)

    ##### iwlist scan #######################

    lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

    enp8s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

    eno1      No scan results

    ##### module infos ######################

    [cfg80211]
    filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-54-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
    description:    wireless configuration support
    license:        GPL
    author:         Johannes Berg
    srcversion:     46F63B461AA5E38D042F531
    depends:        
    intree:         Y
    vermagic:       4.8.0-54-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
    parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
    parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
    parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

    [rt3290sta]
    filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-54-generic/updates/dkms/rt3290sta.ko
    version:        2.6.0.0_rev1
    srcversion:     073AC1AA84019DBCFEC8F58
    depends:        
    vermagic:       4.8.0-54-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
    parm:           mac:rt28xx: wireless mac addr (charp)

    ##### module parameters #################

    [cfg80211]
    bss_entries_limit: 1000
    cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
    ieee80211_regdom: 00

    ##### /etc/modules ######################

    ##### modprobe options ##################

    [/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
    blacklist ath_pci

    [/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
    blacklist evbug
    blacklist usbmouse
    blacklist usbkbd
    blacklist eepro100
    blacklist de4x5
    blacklist eth1394
    blacklist snd_intel8x0m
    blacklist snd_aw2
    blacklist i2c_i801
    blacklist prism54
    blacklist bcm43xx
    blacklist garmin_gps
    blacklist asus_acpi
    blacklist snd_pcsp
    blacklist pcspkr
    blacklist amd76x_edac

    [/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ralink.conf]
    blacklist rt2800pci
    blacklist rt2x00pci

    [/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
    alias net-pf-3 off
    alias net-pf-6 off
    alias net-pf-9 off
    alias net-pf-11 off
    alias net-pf-12 off
    alias net-pf-19 off
    alias net-pf-21 off
    alias net-pf-36 off

    [/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
    remove iwlwifi \
    (/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
    && /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

    [/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
    softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

    ##### rc.local ##########################

    exit 0

    ##### pm-utils ##########################

    ##### udev rules ########################

    ##### dmesg #############################

    [   11.875838] rt2860 0000:0a:00.0 eno1: renamed from ra0
    [   21.584577] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp8s0: link is not ready
    [   21.882126] r8169 0000:08:00.0 enp8s0: link down (repeated 2 times)
    [   21.882191] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp8s0: link is not ready
    [   23.551707] r8169 0000:08:00.0 enp8s0: link up
    [   23.551718] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp8s0: link becomes ready
    [   26.865263] <==== rt28xx_init, Status=0
    [   27.405005] /var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/src/os/linux/../../common/cmm_asic.c:2608 assert KeyIdx < 4failed (repeated 2 times)

    ########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Please visit [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/300665) and edit the question to include results

Comment: @Jeremy31: Edited the question as per your direction. Thanks for the heads up...

Comment: @Jeremy31: please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove the driver you installed

```
cd ~/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508
sudo make uninstall
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ralink.conf
sudo dkms uninstall -m rt3290sta -v 2.6.0.0 -all
sudo dkms remove -m rt3290sta -v 2.6.0.0 -all
```

Disable wireless power management with

```
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

Reboot

Comment: As directed, I uninstalled the drivers. But then I cannot turn on wifi. So I installed this driver.
https://github.com/the-dagger/RaLink-RT3290-Drivers-Ubuntu
Then I got the amber light of wifi hardware switch back to white. But wifi is still searching for networks. No connections are being listed.

Comment: I am putting the new wireless-info.txt result as the new answer

Comment: You didn't follow my instructions as /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ralink.conf still exists, the third command in my answer would have deleted that file so you could use the kernel module that should work

Comment: It might have gotten there when I tried again. Now I removed it. Please see the updated wirelessinfo in the answer.

Comment: `sudo sed -i 's/rt3290sta/#rt3290sta/' /etc/modules` then blacklist with `echo "blacklist rt3290sta" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rt3290sta.conf`

Comment: I did that as you said. Then the wifi was turned off after rebooting. can't turn on and then after restarting network manager, it started to list connections. I could connect. But then I rebooted to check whether it works and saw that it isnt working.

Comment: I repeated it by manually checking /etc/modules and blacklisting the rt3290sta and then added the entry blacklist rt3290sta in /etc/modprobe.d/rt3290sta.conf  as you suggested. Dear @Jeremy31, I am now posting this comment via my Ralink Wifi hardware. Everything solved, and I am enjoying wifi seemlessly. You saved my profession. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

This is the new wireless-info.txt output. I managed to make bluetooth work using the first answer of [RT3290 Ralink driver in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/756166/rt3290-ralink-driver-in-ubuntu)

I installed this driver for getting wifi. 
github.com/the-dagger/RaLink-RT3290-Drivers-Ubuntu 
Then I got the amber light of wifi hardware switch back to white. But wifi is still searching for networks. No connections are being listed. 
Kindly look at the new wireless-info.txt:

```
 ########## wireless info START ##########

 Report from: 16 Jul 2017 18:41 IST +0530

 Booted last: 16 Jul 2017 00:00 IST +0530

 Script from: 25 Mar 2017 07:04 UTC +0000

 ##### release ###########################

 Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
 Description:   Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
 Release:   16.04
 Codename:  xenial

 ##### kernel ############################

 Linux 4.8.0-58-generic #63~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 26 18:08:51 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

 Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

 ##### desktop ###########################

 GNOME

 ##### lspci #############################

 08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [103c:2212]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

 0a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
    DeviceName:  
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter [103c:18ec]

 ##### lsusb #############################

 Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b40e Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HP Truevision HD camera
 Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
 Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
 Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
 Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

 ##### PCMCIA card info ##################

 ##### rfkill ############################

 0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
 1: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
 2: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

 ##### lsmod #############################

 hp_wmi                 16384  0
 rt2800pci              16384  0
 rt2800mmio             20480  1 rt2800pci
 rt2800lib              94208  2 rt2800mmio,rt2800pci
 rt2x00pci              16384  1 rt2800pci
 rt2x00mmio             16384  2 rt2800mmio,rt2800pci
 rt2x00lib              57344  5 rt2800lib,rt2x00pci,rt2800mmio,rt2x00mmio,rt2800pci
 mac80211              761856  3 rt2800lib,rt2x00pci,rt2x00lib
 cfg80211              581632  2 rt2x00lib,mac80211
 eeprom_93cx6           16384  1 rt2800pci
 sparse_keymap          16384  2 intel_hid,hp_wmi
 rt3290sta            1159168  1
 mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
 wmi                    16384  3 mxm_wmi,nouveau,hp_wmi

 ##### interfaces ########################

 auto lo
 iface lo inet loopback

 ##### ifconfig ##########################

 eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eno1' [IF1]>  
           UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
           RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
           TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
           collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
           RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
           Interrupt:16 

 enp8s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp8s0' [IF2]>  
           UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
           RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
           TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
           collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
           RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

 lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
           inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
           inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
           UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
           RX packets:520 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
           TX packets:520 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
           collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
           RX bytes:38640 (38.6 KB)  TX bytes:38640 (38.6 KB)

 ##### iwconfig ##########################

 lo        no wireless extensions.

 enp8s0    no wireless extensions.

 eno1      Ralink STA  ESSID:""  Nickname:"RT3290STA"
           Mode:Auto  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
           Bit Rate:1 Mb/s   
           RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
           Link Quality=10/100  Signal level:0 dBm  Noise level:0 dBm
           Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
           Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

 ##### route #############################

 Kernel IP routing table
 Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

 ##### resolv.conf #######################

 ##### network managers ##################

 Installed:

    NetworkManager

 Running:

 root       876     1  0 18:40 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

 ##### NetworkManager info ###############

 GENERAL.DEVICE:                         <MAC address>
 GENERAL.TYPE:                           bt
 GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceBt
 GENERAL.VENDOR:                         
 GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        
 GENERAL.DRIVER:                         bluez
 GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 
 GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
 GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC address>
 GENERAL.MTU:                            0
 GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
 GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
 GENERAL.UDI:                            /org/bluez/hci0/dev_14_30_C6_AA_28_4E
 GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
 GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
 GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
 GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
 GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
 GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
 GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
 GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
 GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
 GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
 GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
 CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
 CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
 CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
 BLUETOOTH.CAPABILITIES:                 NAP
 CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{2}
 CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   0e3cc815-a319-4b65-9528-a6b035092190 | XT1033 Network

 GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eno1
 GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
 GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
 GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Ralink corp.
 GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe (Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter)
 GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rt2860
 GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 
 GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
 GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'eno1' [IF1]>
 GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
 GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
 GENERAL.REASON:                         42 (The supplicant is now available)
 GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:0a:00.0/net/eno1
 GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
 GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
 GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
 GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
 GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
 GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
 GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
 GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
 GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
 GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
 GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
 CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
 CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
 CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
 WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
 WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
 WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
 WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
 WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
 WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     no
 WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
 WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
 WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   no
 CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{0}
 CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   10953013-4c3d-4251-be15-910924e67ca3 | Hotspot

 GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp8s0
 GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
 GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
 GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
 GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
 GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
 GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
 GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12
 GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp8s0' [IF2]>
 GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
 GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
 GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
 GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:08:00.0/net/enp8s0
 GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
 GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
 GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
 GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
 GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
 GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
 GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
 GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
 GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
 GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
 GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
 CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
 CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
 CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
 WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
 CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

 SSID  BSSID  MODE  CHAN  FREQ  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  ACTIVE  * 

 ##### NetworkManager.state ##############

 [main]
 NetworkingEnabled=true
 WirelessEnabled=true
 WWANEnabled=true

 ##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

 [main]
 plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
 dns=dnsmasq

 [ifupdown]
 managed=false

 ##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

 [[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot]] (600 root)
 [connection] id=Hotspot | type=wifi | autoconnect=false | permissions=
 [wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'eno1' [IF1]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Dope
 [ipv4] method=shared
 [ipv6] method=auto

 ##### iw reg get ########################

 Region: Asia/Kolkata (based on set time zone)

 country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

 ##### iwlist channels ###################

 lo        no frequency information.

 enp8s0    no frequency information.

 eno1      11 channels in total; available frequencies :
           Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
           Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
           Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
           Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
           Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
           Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
           Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
           Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
           Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
           Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
           Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
           Current Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)

 ##### iwlist scan #######################

 lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

 enp8s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

 eno1      No scan results

 ##### module infos ######################

 [rt2800pci]
 filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-58-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ralink/rt2x00/rt2800pci.ko
 license:        GPL
 firmware:       rt2860.bin
 description:    Ralink RT2800 PCI & PCMCIA Wireless LAN driver.
 version:        2.3.0
 author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
 srcversion:     4D2CAAE95D28B3DF4F72A52
 depends:        rt2x00lib,rt2800lib,rt2800mmio,rt2x00mmio,rt2x00pci,eeprom_93cx6
 intree:         Y
 vermagic:       4.8.0-58-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
 parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption. (bool)

 [rt2800mmio]
 filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-58-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ralink/rt2x00/rt2800mmio.ko
 license:        GPL
 description:    rt2800 MMIO library
 version:        2.3.0
 author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
 srcversion:     DBE617B0243C0FEB62786D4
 depends:        rt2800lib,rt2x00lib,rt2x00mmio
 intree:         Y
 vermagic:       4.8.0-58-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

 [rt2800lib]
 filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-58-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ralink/rt2x00/rt2800lib.ko
 license:        GPL
 description:    Ralink RT2800 library
 version:        2.3.0
 author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com, Bartlomiej Zolnierkiewicz
 srcversion:     7092408A4EF1A70FC0C7538
 depends:        rt2x00lib,mac80211
 intree:         Y
 vermagic:       4.8.0-58-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

 [rt2x00pci]
 filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-58-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ralink/rt2x00/rt2x00pci.ko
 license:        GPL
 description:    rt2x00 pci library
 version:        2.3.0
 author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
 srcversion:     D84965563CC7530CFFD2269
 depends:        rt2x00lib,mac80211
 intree:         Y
 vermagic:       4.8.0-58-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

 [rt2x00mmio]
 filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-58-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ralink/rt2x00/rt2x00mmio.ko
 license:        GPL
 description:    rt2x00 mmio library
 version:        2.3.0
 author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
 srcversion:     02CA9DA77FC2C7FCCC58176
 depends:        rt2x00lib
 intree:         Y
 vermagic:       4.8.0-58-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

 [rt2x00lib]
 filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-58-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ralink/rt2x00/rt2x00lib.ko
 license:        GPL
 description:    rt2x00 library
 version:        2.3.0
 author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
 srcversion:     CF930122B7900096FC259FA
 depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
 intree:         Y
 vermagic:       4.8.0-58-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

 [mac80211]
 filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-58-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
 license:        GPL
 description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
 srcversion:     9AF49B72127065FCF655D6A
 depends:        cfg80211
 intree:         Y
 vermagic:       4.8.0-58-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
 parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
 parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
 parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
 parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
 parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
 parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

 [cfg80211]
 filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-58-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
 description:    wireless configuration support
 license:        GPL
 author:         Johannes Berg
 srcversion:     46F63B461AA5E38D042F531
 depends:        
 intree:         Y
 vermagic:       4.8.0-58-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
 parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
 parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
 parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

 [rt3290sta]
 filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-58-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt3290sta.ko
 version:        2.6.0.0_rev1
 srcversion:     96CD86FDB670E3BFC172F9B
 depends:        
 vermagic:       4.8.0-58-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
 parm:           mac:rt28xx: wireless mac addr (charp)

 ##### module parameters #################

 [rt2800pci]
 nohwcrypt: N

 [mac80211]
 beacon_loss_count: 7
 ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
 max_nullfunc_tries: 2
 max_probe_tries: 5
 minstrel_vht_only: Y
 probe_wait_ms: 500

 [cfg80211]
 bss_entries_limit: 1000
 cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
 ieee80211_regdom: 00

 ##### /etc/modules ######################

 rtbth
 rt3290sta

 ##### modprobe options ##################

 [/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
 blacklist ath_pci

 [/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
 blacklist evbug
 blacklist usbmouse
 blacklist usbkbd
 blacklist eepro100
 blacklist de4x5
 blacklist eth1394
 blacklist snd_intel8x0m
 blacklist snd_aw2
 blacklist i2c_i801
 blacklist prism54
 blacklist bcm43xx
 blacklist garmin_gps
 blacklist asus_acpi
 blacklist snd_pcsp
 blacklist pcspkr
 blacklist amd76x_edac

 [/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
 alias net-pf-3 off
 alias net-pf-6 off
 alias net-pf-9 off
 alias net-pf-11 off
 alias net-pf-12 off
 alias net-pf-19 off
 alias net-pf-21 off
 alias net-pf-36 off

 [/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
 remove iwlwifi \
 (/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
 && /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

 [/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
 softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

 [/etc/modprobe.d/ralink-bt.conf]
 install rtbth /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install rtbth; mknod /dev/rtbth c 192 0; /usr/bin/rtbt &

 ##### rc.local ##########################

 exit 0

 ##### pm-utils ##########################

 ##### udev rules ########################

 ##### dmesg #############################

 [   19.014281] <==== rt28xx_init, Status=0
 [   19.536406] r8169 0000:08:00.0 enp8s0: link down
 [   19.536459] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp8s0: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
 [   23.627250] /home/neo/tmp/rt3290/src/os/linux/../../common/cmm_asic.c:2608 assert KeyIdx < 4failed (repeated 2 times)

 ########## wireless info END ############
```