# Does the Ubuntu 17.10 need any specific Bluetooth drivers?

Tags: drivers, wireless, bluetooth, 17.10

I am new to ubuntu [linux too] and am dual-booting Ubuntu 17.10 with Windows 10. My bluetooth works in Windows but does not shows in Ubuntu. Do I need any specific driver for that? My model is Asus X550LC.

`dmesg` result: https://pastebin.com/neu40txA

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b40a Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Grep Blue doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of these terminal commands: `lsusb` and also: `dmesg | grep blue` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I would just search google for RT3290 bluetooth linux and see if there is a solution that works lately.  I searched a while back and it was rather confusing.  This [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/924632/rt3290-wifi-not-listing-connections-in-ubuntu-gnome-16-04) has an accepted answer but I cannot verify if it works