# Wifi not showing on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, realtek-wireless

I am aware this question had been asked and answered before [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/769521/wifi-networks-are-not-showing-in-ubuntu-16-04) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775165/wifi-network-list-not-showing-in-ubuntu-16-04/775181#775181), but I tried their suggested solutions with no luck.

The problem is as stated - wifi network list does not show up in the GUI, it doesn't even have the option turn wifi on/off. It used to be that sometimes it would show and sometimes it wouldn't, and in some cases it would randomly disconnect from the wifi network and wouldn't show them again.

In trying to fix that I found somewhere (i can't seem to find it again) stating I should use the files in [here](https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware) to fix the problem. I copied the files onto `/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174`, replacing the files in there. I stupidly didn't save a copy of the other files, and ever since I replaced them the wifi doesn't show up at all.

So basically this is two related questions in one:

1. Where do I find the original files for the `./QCA6174/hw2.1` and `./QCA6174/hw3.0` folders? (is this even necessary)
2. How do I permanently solve this problem of wifi networks not showing or randomly disconnecting?

here is some possibly relevant info:

lshw:

> `~$ sudo lshw -C network
>     *-network
>
>          description: Ethernet interface
>          product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
>          vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
>          physical id: 0
>          bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
>          logical name: enp2s0
>          version: 08
>          serial: 50:7b:9d:cc:bc:da
>          size: 10Mbit/s
>          capacity: 100Mbit/s
>          width: 64 bits
>          clock: 33MHz
>          capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
>          configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-2_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
>          resources: irq:45 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c1004000-c1004fff memory:c1000000-c1003fff
>     *-network
>          description: Ethernet interface
>          physical id: 3
>          logical name: bnep0
>          serial: 44:1c:a8:65:92:6c
>          capabilities: ethernet physical
>          configuration: broadcast=yes ip=192.168.44.206 multicast=yes`

lspci:

> `~$ lspci -v
>   ...
>   02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 08)
>       Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
>       Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
>       I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
>       Memory at c1004000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
>       Memory at c1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
>       Capabilities: <access denied>
>       Kernel driver in use: r8169
>       Kernel modules: r8169`

rfkill:

> `~$ sudo rfkill list
>   0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
>       Soft blocked: no
>       Hard blocked: no
>   1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
>       Soft blocked: no
>       Hard blocked: no
>   2: hci0: Bluetooth
>       Soft blocked: no
>       Hard blocked: no`

iconfig:

> `~$ sudo iwconfig
>   enp2s0    no wireless extensions.
>   lo        no wireless extensions.
>   bnep0     no wireless extensions.`

Comment: Is there an option in BIOS to enable WLAN

Comment: I will try it and let you know if it worked

Comment: The WLAN was already enabled, so sadly that didn't make a difference. Any other ideas?

Comment: You might want to power down and remove the wifi card and then reinstall it to see if it shows in terminal results then