# Can't View Wi-fi Networks in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, ralink

Let me first say I have tried different things before posting.After installing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS the wifi was totally disabled.  It showed Wi-fi disabled. After trying the all solutions in this question [How do I get an RT3290 wireless card to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760838/how-do-i-get-an-rt3290-wireless-card-to-work) it started showing Wi-fi Networks but there was no connections available. Then I tried the solutions in [Wifi networks are not showing in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/769521/wifi-networks-are-not-showing-in-ubuntu-16-04), but then there was absolutely nothing called Wi-fi Networks. Then I did 
`

```
sudo ifconfig rename3 up *(rename3 is the logical name of my wireless interface)*

sudo systemctl restart network-manager
```

After this it went back to previous stage but still it was not showing any available wifi connections.

**sudo lshw -C network**

```
*-network DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: rename3
       version: 00
       serial: 1c:3e:84:58:05:33
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=RALINK WLAN latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=Ralink STA
       resources: irq:16 memory:63510000-6351ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0e:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 05
       serial: 2c:59:e5:a4:ce:e4
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw ip=192.168.0.105 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:26 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:63404000-63404fff memory:63400000-63403fff
```

I have just switched from windows and I am kind of lost, for two days I've been trying to make it work. Please some help would be really great and I really want to keep using Linux.

After trying things in ubuntu 16.04 I installed 14.04. After fresh installation

**rfkill list all**

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes
```

**lsmod | grep -e wmi -e laptop**

```
    hp_wmi                 16384  0 
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd                    81920  17 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
wmi                    20480  1 hp_wmi
```

Then I found another question that was solved [Ralink rt3290 wifi driver is not working in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455030/ralink-rt3290-wifi-driver-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04) and tried the solution then something changed.
**rfkill list all** is showing nothing and **sudo lshw -C network** gave the following output where `*-network DISABLED` of the wireless interface was no longer there.

```
 *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: ra0
       version: 00
       serial: 1c:3e:84:58:05:33
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=RALINK WLAN latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=Ralink STA
       resources: irq:16 memory:63510000-6351ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0e:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 05
       serial: 2c:59:e5:a4:ce:e4
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw ip=192.168.0.104 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:26 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:63404000-63404fff memory:63400000-63403fff
```

Another information I got when I did
**nmcli dev**

```
DEVICE     TYPE              STATE        
eth0       802-3-ethernet    unavailable  
ra0        802-11-wireless   disconnected 
usb0       802-3-ethernet    connected
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command *rfkill list all* I suspect that the hardware switch is set to disable the wireless.

Comment: There was nothing showing in _rfkill list all_ . It just went to the next line. I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 as it might be more stable. Then Running rfkill list all showed softblock and hardblock both yes. I tried unblocking now it's only hard block that got yes. I tried the wifi switch on the keyboard to turn on or off. Nothing worked.

Comment: May we actually see the output? `rfkill list all` Please also add: `lsmod | grep -e wmi -e laptop`

Comment: After fresh installation of ubuntu 14.04 the outputs are
**rfkill list all**
`0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes`

Comment: As I suspected, hard blocked. How about the `lsmod | grep -e wmi -e laptop`? What brand and model laptop is it?

Comment: I edited the question. Please see.

Comment: Have you tried hitting the Wi-Fi off switch on the laptop to turn it on?

Comment: Laptop brand is HP 1000 Notebook PC and the model number is 1000-1305TX
@EODCraftStaff  Yes I have tried, the switch isn't working, it light in the switch stays white all the time.