# Wifi connections not showing up on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, wireless

I have a fresh install of ubuntu 16.04 in a thinkpad e470 but no wifi appears nor the option to enable the wifi. I already tried enabling it using the fn key, but it still doesn't work.

I already tried many different approaches, including trying to update the packages, checking for drivers, restarting network manager and following these solutions:

- [No Wifi after Fresh Installation of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2349245)
- [Wifi networks are not showing in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/769521/wifi-networks-are-not-showing-in-ubuntu-16-04/775425)

Unfortunately none of this worked :/

The output from `lshw -C network` is as follow:

```
*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 10
       serial: 54:e1:ad:a7:cf:25
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 ip=192.168.1.88 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:122 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f1104000-f1104fff memory:f1100000-f1103fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:c000(size=256) memory:f1000000-f100ffff
```

The output for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net`:

```
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:505b]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:c821]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:c024]
```

Comment: Please edit to include results for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net`

Comment: Hi @Jeremy31,  I posted the output of it :)

Comment: You can follow this Solution : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071310/wifi-adapter-not-found-realtek-r8822be/1121635#1121635

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally managed to make it work. What was missing was the driver 8821ce.

I followed the answer found here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/379049/realtek-wifi-driver-problem-in-linux-mint-18-2