# Wifi adapter not found Realtek R8822BE

Tags: drivers, realtek

I have a problem with wi-fi adapter. They are not found!
My laptop is HP-Pavilion-15-cw0xxx with Windows 10. In Windows 10 wifi works very well!
I did following:

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2 
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b822]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:831b]
    Kernel modules: **r8822be**, wl, rtl8822be

ilya@ilya-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-15-cw0xxx:~$ sudo lshw -c network  
[sudo] password for ilya: 
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fea00000-fea0ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 15
       serial: b4:b6:86:ea:93:36
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=**r8169** driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.0.102 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:46 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fe904000-fe904fff memory:fe900000-fe903fff
```

Also I add wl, rtl8822be in blacklist and do following:

```
echo -e "blacklist r8822be\n\# blacklist wl\nblacklist rtl8822be" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/test_ban.conf
```

Also, I even switch off secure boot, but it doesn't help.

I am a biginner user of Ubuntu.
Do you have any advices or solutions of my proplems?

Best regars,
Ilia

Comment: pHeLiOn, thanks a lot, but I solved this problem in different way. I add, wl anr rtl8822be to black list and switch off secure boot!

Comment: Glad you got it all working! I'll delete my comment about removing 'test_ban.conf' (that was just a guess). It's probably worth noting that this seems like an unusual way to get the rtl8822be working (bcmwl-kernel-source is usually to do with broadcom wifi chipsets) but I'm happy to hear it's all up and running anyway! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step1 : You must need a temporary ethernet internet connection (LAN cable or USB tethering from phone or wifi adapter)

Step2 : Once you have an active internet connection. Open the terminal and check for Wifi Driver 
Available in the kernel

**$ lspci -knn | grep -i Net -A2**

From the output we can see the current wifi driver is :

Lenovo RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter

Step3 : Search for ‘**RTL8821CE Driver**’, there is not yet a Wifi Driver for the Realtek RTL8821CE in the official Ubuntu Repositories.

There is a git repo : https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce.git . Clone to that git repo

**$ git clone https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce.git**

Step 4 (Optional):If you are getting any error like git not installed or gcc is not present , install them by:

**$ apt install gcc**
**$ apt install git**
**$ apt install make**

After installing above three packages rerun step3.

Step 4 : Once the git repository for the RTL8821CE Driver is downloaded, go to corresponding folder :

**$ cd rtl8821ce**

Step 5 : Compile the driver by using make utility.

**$ make all**
**$ make install**

Step 6 : Insert the driver module to the kernel using ‘modprobe’ program.

**modprobe -a 8821ce**

Step 7 : reboot if necessary

Step 8 : We’ve successfully resolved the wifi problem by using above steps, But the wifi connection got intermittent without any specific reason, later we fixed that issue by changing power management options in Ubuntu.

**$ nano /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf**

**Change wifi.powersave from 3 to 2.**

Please let me know if you ever faced any issues, I’ll be happy to solve.

Comment: merinkjacob, thank you for your answer. I hope it will be useful for other users. Fortunately, I solved my problem six month ago.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem that:

```
echo -e "# blacklist r8822be\n\ blacklist wl\nblacklist rtl8822be" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/test_ban.conf

sudo apt remove bcmwl-kernel-source
```

And switch off secure boot!