# No Wi-fi adapter found on Lennovo laptop running Ubuntu 20.04LTS and a rlt8822be realtek wifi adapter

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, wireless, realtek

I've seen similar posts in this forum but none of them have worked for me. I recently adopted linux and the first couple of days my wifi was working fine but all of a sudden there is no way on earth to get it to work. I been reading a lot in the subject and found lots of similar issues on the internet. I don't think that many have been solved. Is there a way to actually get a driver for the rlt8822BE in ubuntu 20.04?

I have tried answers from the following posts:

https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88

[Still No wifi adapter for Realtek RTL8822BE found in 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067286/still-no-wifi-adapter-for-realtek-rtl8822be-found-in-18-04)

[Wifi adapter not found Realtek R8822BE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071310/wifi-adapter-not-found-realtek-r8822be)

[Lenovo's Wifi RTL8822BE not working on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1295251/lenovos-wifi-rtl8822be-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04)

https://tutorialforlinux.com/2020/08/06/step-by-step-ubuntu-20-04-realtek-rtl8821ce-driver-installation/2/

I blacklisted conflicting drivers, tried installing a bunch of them, reinstalled linux from scratch several times, nothing seems to work.

Here is some useful information:
When running **lshw -C network**

```
 *-network                 
        description: Ethernet interface
        product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
        vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
        physical id: 0
        bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
        logical name: enp8s0
        version: 15
        serial: e8:6a:64:bf:74:7b
        size: 1Gbit/s
        capacity: 1Gbit/s
        width: 64 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd
 autonegotiation
        configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.13.0-27-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2
 02/26/15 ip=10.0.0.230 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted
 pair speed=1Gbit/s
        resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a4204000-a4204fff memory:a4200000-a4203fff
```

When running **lsmod | grep rtw**:

```
rtw_8822be             16384  0
rtw_8822b             225280  1 rtw_8822be
rtw_pci                24576  1 rtw_8822be
rtw_core              204800  2 rtw_8822b,rtw_pci
mac80211             1028096  2 rtw_core,rtw_pci
cfg80211              888832  2 rtw_core,mac80211
```

I think rtw_8822b should be blacklisted not sure if it is normal that is still appears in there.

Also, running **lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3** results in the following (from where I found out I have the RLT8822BE network controller.

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter [10ec:b822] (rev ff)
    Kernel modules: rtw_8822be
08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:38b4]
```

Please let me know if you know something I can try.

Edit:
When running **dmesg | grep -i rtw**

```
[   62.744521] rtw_core: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[   62.744605] rtw_core: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[   62.760936] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: Firmware version 27.2.0, H2C version 13
[   62.821808] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: failed to read hw feature report
[   64.822026] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0
[   64.822030] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: failed to setup chip efuse info
[   64.822032] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: failed to setup chip information
[   64.852572] rtw_8822be: probe of 0000:07:00.0 failed with error -16
```

Comment: Two questions for you: (1) which model of Lenovo are you using? (2) have you tried booting into a Live Session with the Ubuntu Installation USB to see if the wireless device works there? This would be a quick way to identify if there might be a configuration issue or a hardware preventing the WiFi device from working correctly 

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `dmesg | grep -i rtw`

Comment: I am using a lenovo Legion y530 and just tried booting into a live session from USB it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and tried the same solutions to no joy. I'm quite adept system admin, usually with RHEL family, but have no solution. Decided to return to the windows (still dual boot on my laptop), the Wifi is disconnected, and I try to reconnect again with normal success, and decided to reboot again to Ubuntu 23.10. And guess what... I'm typing this text on Ubuntu using the (magically) restored Wifi.
I dunno the problem is with the driver, or the physical chipset (no indication on windows), or just plain bad luck.