# ubuntu 16.04 is automatically connecting to its own created wifi-hotspot via create_ap. And avilable wifi networks are not detected

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, network-manager

I have been using [create_ap](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap) to create wifi hotspot to connect from my mobile phone, everything was running smoothly with no errors.
(Here is how I create the netwrok `sudo create_ap wlp3s0 wlp3s0 ubuntu-hotspot ubuntu-12345`)

Recently, I restarted my machine for some reason, and after that ubuntu is automatically creating `ubuntu-hotspot` and connecting to it, (I can confirm that the network is running from my mobile phone, it detected the network but it cannot connect to it), and when I hit disconnect the network is gone (I can also confirm from my mobile phone).

The problem is:

1- the above mentioned + `create_ap` is no longer working ( when I attempt to start a network it displays this error `ERROR: Your adapter can not transmit to channel 56, frequency band 5GHz.`)

2- More importantly, No other wifi networks are detected at all.

I can connect to my home network using `connect to hidden Wi-Fi networks` but other wifi networks are not detected

I have tried the proposed solutions in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/769521/wifi-networks-are-not-showing-in-ubuntu-16-04) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46836085/wifi-not-getting-detected-in-ubuntu-16-04) thread and nothing worked.

And here is the output of `sudo lshw -C network`

```
*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 10
       serial: 70:4d:7b:98:f3:50
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:ef204000-ef204fff memory:ef200000-ef203fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 8260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 3a
       serial: f4:8c:50:3c:52:c1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-43-generic firmware=34.0.1 ip=10.57.104.77 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:130 memory:ef100000-ef101fff
```

Answer (score 0):

I partially solved the "wifi is not showing" issue by logging out and logging in again.
Apparently this resets the GUI session.

But when I restart, `create_ap` is (probably) creating the network and it's connecting to it, no further wifi networks are listed except the created hotspot network, I have to hit disconnect and logout-login and this resets the GUI and I can see the wifi networks. (without clicking disconnect logining out and loging in doesn't solve the issue)

It makes sense becuase all drivers and `sudo lshw -C network` output is clean.

I tried to disable `create_ap` service by `systemctl disable create_ap` and reboot, but it didn't work (I had to disconnect from the created hotspot network and logout-login again)

Wierdly, when I rebooted and the hotspot network is created, when I run `systemctl status create_ap` the output is the following:

```
create_ap.service - Create AP Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/create_ap.service; disabled; vendor p
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

It says that the service is disabled and inactive, but somehow the hotspot network is created (I don't understand what is going on here)

> when I attempt to start a network it displays this error ERROR: Your adapter can not transmit to channel 56, frequency band 5GHz.

This error was because the wifi adapter is connecting to the router via 5GHz frequency band, disconnecting and connecting solved the issue (it re-connected via 2.4 GHz frequency band and was able to create a hotspot network)