# Ubuntu 16.04: no wifi broadcasts except mobile hotspots are detected

Tags: 16.04, drivers, network-manager, realtek-wireless, rtl8723be

My original problem was that I kept running into [image: <code>The system is running into low graphics mode</code>] during bootup. Usually, I'd just reboot a few times and the error went away. I even tried following [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error) to resolve it, but it did not help. However, recently the error message persisted after quite a number of reboot attempts, so I decided to continue to boot up. Upon bootup, I found that my WiFi isn't connected and the `Wifi Networks` under the `Networking` tab said `device not ready`. I followed [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/844746/wifi-networks-device-not-ready/862185) and restarted the network manager with `sudo systemctl restart network-manager` and the Wifi started to work. On the next bootup, even that didn't work. I followed [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/921392/870350) and commented out the lines at `/etc/networks/interfaces`, restarted `network-manager` and all the wifi signals disappeared, except the mobile hotspots. I uncommented the lines and the wifi signals reappeared, however, on a reboot, they disappeared again (the lines are still uncommented). Since then, I have been unable to connect or detect my Router's broadcasts and have no other options but to use my mobile hotspots. I even tried reinstalling the wifi drivers [as instructed here](https://askubuntu.com/a/635629/870350), but in vain.

Outputs from few commands:
**Command: inxi -F**
Output:

```
System:    Host: host Kernel: 4.15.0-33-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Unity 
           Distro: Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (Xenial Xerus) 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: HP product: HP Notebook v: Type1ProductConfigId serial: <root required> 
           Mobo: HP model: 80C1 v: 96.40 serial: <root required> UEFI [Legacy]: Insyde v: F.1B date: 10/19/2015 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT1 charge: 21.8 Wh condition: 26.4/41.4 Wh (64%) 
CPU:       Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Core i3-5005U bits: 64 type: MT MCP L2 cache: 3072 KiB 
           Speed: 1896 MHz min/max: 500/1900 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1291 2: 1243 3: 1237 4: 1373 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics driver: i915 v: kernel 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.19.6 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa resolution: 1366x768~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2) v: 4.5 Mesa 18.0.5 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Broadwell-U Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Device-2: Intel Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k4.15.0-33-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Realtek RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet driver: r8169 
           IF: enp7s0 state: down mac: dc:4a:3e:d1:b0:03 
           Device-2: Realtek RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter driver: rtl8723be 
           IF: wlp13s0 state: up mac: 48:e2:44:80:58:95 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 931.51 GiB used: 135.44 GiB (14.5%) 
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Seagate model: ST1000LM024 HN-M101MBB size: 931.51 GiB 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 912.91 GiB used: 135.44 GiB (14.8%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda1 
           ID-2: swap-1 size: 3.92 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda5 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 42.0 C mobo: N/A 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:      Processes: 229 Uptime: 23m Memory: 3.78 GiB used: 1.64 GiB (43.4%) Shell: bash inxi: 3.0.22
```

**Command: lspci**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Camarillo Device (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev e3)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev e3)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev e3)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Thermal Management Controller (rev 03)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 07)
0d:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

**Command: ifconfig && iwconfig**

```
enp7s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr dc:4a:3e:d1:b0:03  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1025 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1025 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:89243 (89.2 KB)  TX bytes:89243 (89.2 KB)

wlp13s0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 48:e2:44:80:58:95  
          inet addr:192.168.43.144  Bcast:192.168.43.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::e692:e7ed:b3cb:3a1a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10504 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8878 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:6949200 (6.9 MB)  TX bytes:1689349 (1.6 MB)

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp7s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp13s0   IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Moto C 6768"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 5E:51:88:FD:7D:5A   
          Bit Rate=7.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=40/70  Signal level=-70 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:8   Missed beacon:0
```